# Nativescript Sidekick cloud build error Android

Tags: nativescript

When I try to build my NS application using Sidekick I get the following error:

```html
[18-07-31 08:06:59.535] (CLI) Command npm install tns-android@3.4.0 --silent --save-exact --save failed with exit code 1 Error output: 
[18-07-31 08:06:59.535] (CLI)  Unhandled rejection Error: Integrity check failed:
[18-07-31 08:06:59.535] (CLI)   Wanted: sha512-UGlRKABh3ZZnhZq8hKc19NIkWNiFpuKNri8fMOjuV6h6qsVVf+ua3g3JqUJoufkZo95yhERjTBa8nkV3RY3g+g==
[18-07-31 08:06:59.535] (CLI)    Found: sha512-zX507Sx/iLCoCgqUwF9e9HtFzot1piqis7SEQQQy9TxNBkd4KdRd+74vw9YjGb51QMKHdOOHYkC3q+9XtU7fNw==
[18-07-31 08:06:59.535] (CLI)     at checksumError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/lib/content/write.js:155:13)
[18-07-31 08:06:59.535] (CLI)     at write (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/lib/content/write.js:33:22)
[18-07-31 08:06:59.535] (CLI)     at putData (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/put.js:11:10)
[18-07-31 08:06:59.535] (CLI)     at Object.x.put (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/locales/en.js:28:37)
[18-07-31 08:06:59.535] (CLI)     at readFileAsync.then.data (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/file.js:38:28)
[18-07-31 08:06:59.535] (CLI)     at tryCatcher (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
[18-07-31 08:06:59.535] (CLI)     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
[18-07-31 08:06:59.535] (CLI)     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
[18-07-31 08:06:59.535] (CLI)     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
[18-07-31 08:06:59.535] (CLI)     at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
[18-07-31 08:06:59.535] (CLI)     at Promise._fulfill (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:638:18)
[18-07-31 08:06:59.535] (CLI)     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/nodeback.js:42:21
[18-07-31 08:06:59.535] (CLI)     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
[18-07-31 08:06:59.535] (CLI)     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)
[18-07-31 08:07:00.969] (CLI) bc_BnGC7LDWhYFdbMASM3
[18-07-31 08:07:06.156] Build failed.
```

I can build locally using VS Code, but the cloud build fails.  Below is my package.json:

```html
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.company.myapp",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "3.4.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "3.4.0"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "2.20.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.14",
    "nativescript-appversion": "1.4.1",
    "nativescript-zendesk": "file:nativescript-zendesk-1.0.0.tgz",
    "nativescript-email": "1.5.1",
    "nativescript-exit": "1.0.1",
    "nativescript-fingerprint-auth": "6.0.3",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "1.2.0",
    "nativescript-loading-indicator": "2.4.0",
    "nativescript-masked-text-field": "2.0.2",
    "nativescript-numeric-keyboard": "3.0.3",
    "nativescript-pdf-view": "2.0.1",
    "nativescript-phone": "1.3.1",
    "nativescript-push-notifications": "1.1.3",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "1.0.4",
    "nativescript-ui-calendar": "^3.5.1",
    "nativescript-zendesk-with-chat": "0.2.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.4.5",
    "babel-types": "6.4.5",
    "babylon": "6.4.5",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "0.5.1",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "^3.4.0",
    "typescript": "2.5.3"
  }
}
```

I cannot find any information on this error.  Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

EDIT:  I tried removing and adding the android platform and got the same error.

I also opened an issue [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/docs/issues/1289).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out the reason for this, but after removing the node_modules, hooks, removing both platforms and adding them back on, suddenly everything works again.

It seems that sometimes the project creates some internal conflicts and clearing everything up and starting fresh works.